# I get "message": "Unauthenticated" laravel passport api when I want to get user logged in

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Postman APi testing]

Get user method I used

```
   public function getUser() {
$user = Auth::user();
return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus); 
}
```

Api routes

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function(){
Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login');
Route::post('register', 'Api\AuthController@register');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
Route::post('getUser', 'Api\AuthController@getUser');
});
```

});

Please help me guys I m stuck I ll appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

When calling routes that are protected by Passport, your application's API consumers should specify their access token as a `Bearer` token in the `Authorization` header of their request. For example, when using the Guzzle HTTP library:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

`$accessToken` is the token generated by the api when logging in.

You must submit this token in all requests that require authentication in your API

Comment: You can't tell from the capture that they're Headers. If you are sending the token and it still says Unauthenticated then you are either sending the token incorrectly or the token is not correct.